# how to disable bulk_action in django 1.1 beta

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

I am using django 1.1 beta release. In my project I want to use bulk_action in some models only. How can I disable bulk_action from the remaining models? I want to totally remove action label along with the checkbox; in other words as it would look in Django 1.02.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used the solution provided in django docs

```
def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
    if request.user:
        del actions['delete_selected']
    return actions
```

this removed all the actions from my change page

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for - I can't find any reference to `bulk_action` online. Bulk actions were introduced in Django 1.1 (see the [release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1-beta-1/#admin-actions)), so I guess you're referring to removing bulk actions for certain models' admin pages.

If you want no bulk actions available for a given `ModelAdmin`, simply set `ModelAdmin.actions` to `None`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = None
```

from the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-actions).

I don't think this method will remove the checkboxes, or make the listings page look like Django 1.02, it'll just remove the list of bulk actions from the dropdown.

Comment: in what way? Do you get an error message? Does it not do what it says?